# Можно ли преобразовать код в одну строку

Tags: python

Есть следующий код. Можно ли его переписать в одну строку?

```
b = list(bin(5))
for i in range(3, len(b), 2):
    b[i], b[i - 1] = b[i - 1], b[i]
b = "".join(b)
b = int(b, 2)
```

Comment: Можно, но это будет очень длинная и малопонятная строчка

Comment: Это делать можно, только если вы поспорили, что это можно сделать. Если же вам нужно строкой чтобы куда-то вставить этот код для вызова, то оформите его функцией и дергайте как функцию одной строкой. В остальном не нужно делать не читаемым код.

Comment: @Xander это вопрос просто из разряда любопытства

Comment: Написать в одну строку можно если это мусорный код который ненужно обслуживать в будущем, иначе лучше написать пару лишних строк.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

если в лоб микроскопом по гвоздям, то так например:

```
value = 152
new = int('0b' + ''.join(obj[0] + obj[1] for obj in zip(('0' * (len(str(bin(value))[2:]) % 2) + str(bin(value))[2:])[1::2], ('0' * (len(str(bin(value))[2:]) % 2) + str(bin(value))[2:])[::2])), 2)

print(new)
```

вариант 2:

```
new = ((value & 0b10101010101010101) << 1) | ((value & 0b101010101010101010) >> 1)
```

`0b10101010101010101` можно составить нужной длины зная число `value` через логарифмы получить число `0b11...111 / 0b11` - т.е. `(2**n - 1) / 3`, где `n` - длина числа в битах (`log(value) / log(2) + 1`)

как вариант полного решения:

```
new = ((value & ((2**math.ceil(math.log2(value)) - 1) // 3)) >> 1) | ((value & (((2**math.ceil(math.log2(value)) - 1) // 3 * 2) + 1)) << 1)
```

Comment: вариант 2 - красота! не успел нагуглить ))

Comment: [отсюда?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3758439/5741205) Этот вариант надо "обрабатывать напильником" в зависимости от того, сколько байт занимает исходное число ;)

Comment: второй вариант не будет работать с очень большими числами, но все равно +1

Comment: а может кто обьяснить принцип работы второго способа. конструкцию такую впервые вижу?

Comment: @MaxU, просто не стал дописывать (сейчас дописал) как получить нужную маску

Comment: @pelmenx, вам надо поменять соседние биты, поэтому получаем 2 числа у которых установлены только четные и только нечетные биты, дальше те у кого установлены только четные сдвигаем влево, а те у кого установлены нечетные биты право и складываем - по сути это и есть перемещение местами бит - например число `1234` (я специально такие левые биты написал, а не 0,1, чтобы нагляднее было) - первая маска даст число `1030` а вторая маска число `0204`, далее смещая вправо и влево получаем числа `0103` и `2040`, складываем и получаем `2143` - вот так это работает

Comment: в первом варианте `'0b'` не обязателен

Comment: `value = 123456789` - первое и последнее решение возвращают разный результат

Comment: @Danis, и что тогда получится? Восьмиричное число или десятичное в зависимости от старшего бита?

Comment: @0andriy в `int` вторым параметром передаётся `2`

Comment: @Danis, хороший пример, почему однострочники — зло.

Comment: @MaxU, потому что право с лево перепутал и забыл добавить 1, подправил :)

Comment: `value = 1111111111111111111111111111111` ;)

Comment: Кстати можно обойтись без модуля __math__: `((value & ((2**value.bit_length() - 1) // 3)) >> 1) | ((value & (((2**value.bit_length() - 1) // 3 * 2) + 1)) << 1)`